# Change color of points on a plot based on index R

Tags: r

I want to plot anomalies in a dataset with a different color. For that i generated random numbers, injected anomalies based on a condition, and them plotted them. But the plot that i am getting is wrong. Following is the code:

```
n = 1000

a = 25

mu = 0

sigma = 0.5

data = rnorm(n,mu,sigma)

n_data = sample(1:n,25,replace = FALSE)

p_data = sample(1:n,25,replace = FALSE)

plot(data)
points(data[n_data],col=2)
points(data[p_data],col=3)
```

But this gives me a wrong plot. It should show anomalous points distributed among the whole graph, but it shows a plot like this.

[image]

How can i plot the points correctly based on index?

Comment: It appears that you do not need the variable `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you plot your vector `data` without x specified so x is `x1 = 1... xn = length(data)`

just indicate the x corresponding and it will work

```
points(n_data, data[n_data],col=2)
points(p_data, data[p_data],col=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do not have x coordinates for your random values, so the plot will simply give each value an index and treat that as your x-value. You have a total of 1000 points, but only 25 are colored in each of the colored points. If you were to take 1000 colored points they would be spread out just as much.